# jQuery Sortable List - How do I stop the UL container from extending?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have multiple connected ul lists.

There is one large UL list that I've set a max height and width with scrollable y-axis.

The problem is that when I move a item from the large list to another one on the right, the ul container scrolls. I've set overflow-x to hidden but it has no effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/hCzr8/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the position:relative on the ul.lists seems to solve the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/hCzr8/7/

Is there any particular reason in which static positioning isn't adequate for the ul?

Comment: Yes. Thank you that worked. They were remnants from other stuff that I forgot to remove.